# CFTC Futures Market Positioning

Tags: futures

What does CFTC total net contracts number imply about a currency? For example, if total net contract is positive does that mean market is long USD/BRL? Btw I’m checking numbers on Bloomberg, ticker is “CFTC CME Brazilian Real Total Net Contracts/Combined”

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For every buyer of a future, there is a seller so the market is neither long or short by the number of contracts.  This is the net weekly change of the number of open contracts by all the trader categories for Brazilian Real Futures traded on the CME.

Comment: So does that mean in favor of BRL or not?

Comment: Neither. It's just the weekly change in the number of open contracts.